# Query keyup trigger not working in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, keyup

below jQuery onclick keyup trigger not working in chrome and safari but it's working in firefox.

```
 function add_bodyclass ()
{ 
  jQuery('.orig').val(' ').keyup();
}
```

Let me know how to fix the issue.

Comment: use jQuery('.orig').trigger('keyup')

Comment: Share more code to understand why this is not working. Ideally, `trigger` should work. If its not working, there is something else that is conflicting it or stopping it.

Comment: The “ajax search lite” wordpress plugin  to process the blog search in keypress function. So i need to trigger that function in my custom search onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code:

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control text-right" id="amount" autocomplete="off" data-bind="value: amount, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">
<span data-bind="text: amount"/>
```

js code:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    amount: ko.observable(100)
})

$('#amount').val("200");
$('#amount').trigger("keyup");
```

Comment: Your code is working here: Your code is working here: https://jsfiddle.net/dgvykf27/ in Chrom

Comment: The “ajax search lite” wordpress plugin  to process the blog search in keypress function. So i need to trigger that function in my custom search onclick.